# Need gateway/router example using systemd-networkd

Tags: networking, server, 18.04, dhcp, systemd-networkd

Is there a good Ubuntu example of gateway/router using systemd-networkd?

I am trying to find an Ubuntu example of a gateway/router where eth0 is the WAN and eth1 ... ethN are the LAN using systemd-networkd. I need the gateway/router to act as the DHCP server on the LAN side. I need eth0 to be a DHCP client on the WAN side.

NOTE: I have ufw working, ddclient working, and NTP working. I am using Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS in a motherboard with 10 eth ports.

Emphasis: systemd-networkd

Comment: With Ubuntu Desktop version? If you dont need the desktop, consider using router dedicated linux distrib as ipCop or pfSense or ZeroShell

Comment: I am using 18.04 server version. I will investigate. Thank-you.